# Cannot find boot device

Tags: boot, partitioning, ssd, bios, bootloader

I have installed Ubuntu on my Acer aspire 7750, but when I try to run Ubuntu it says: cannot find boot device. I have checked if my SSD is giving any errors with the smart tools and it says it' s ok. I also put my SSD (where Ubuntu has been installed) to boot fist but that also didn' t work. So I am right now running out of options. :
(

My specs are:

Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T5750 @ 2.00GHz × 2

4 GB of memories

1 Terabyte SSD

Bios: insydeH20 ver. 1.27

Comment: Is that the latest firmware from Acer for your system? And does SSD have latest firmware? With only 4GB of RAM, a lighter weight flavor may be better. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie I use Kubuntu on newer desktops & it worked on external SSD (UEFI/gpt) on 2006 BIOS only system with 1.5GB of RAM when I added BIOS boot stanza to internal HDD drive to boot SSD. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report) Use option 2. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Hello oldfred, I have run the program and no I don't think I have the lastest firmware on my system, because I need a snid or a model number and I can' t find that. But what can I do now with the BootInfo summary report?

Comment: Post pastebin side link to report in question above, so we can click on link and see details of your install. Only updated UEFI on my motherboards, but you should be able to put model number in on Acer site to find latest. It may not be very new, but if newer, you should install it.

Comment: Ok, I couldn't find the link where the pastebin is. But I have a link to a ubuntu community where the pastelink is! And can you install a Acer bios update in Ubuntu or do you have to install Windows for example on a VM?

Comment: Here is the link of the pastebin in the community: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2493685

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My laptop is finally running Ubuntu and here is how I have done it:

First you had to make a MS-DOS partitioning table, then in the installer you had to click on: "other" in order to make partitions yourself, finally you had to make **ONE PARTITION** for your root and your boot. So the BIOS can detect it.

Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me twice on an Acer. Changed the hard drive, reinstalled. Worked fine after that.

Comment: That's weird, cause I bought my SSD this year. Could it be something else, because windows is working perfect on the SSD.

Comment: I don't know the ins and out but this is just my experience. Mine was an ssd too. I wonder could tht be something to do with it? Are you dual booting?

Comment: No. I am not dual booting. But I am wondering if my grub got corupted , because when I was installing it on my usb the programm rufus said that my grub isn't compatible and that I have to update it. What do you think?

Comment: Also make sure your system is booting from where you installed Ubuntu and not from the usb for instance.

Comment: I was trying to do that, but I got the same error message. :/

Comment: But do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: If it were me I would try a reinstall of Ubuntu to see if that would work. Let  me know how things go and I hope all goes well.